# jquery ajax success not finding variable div

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have the following code:

```
<script>
function initialData() {
    var patches = [<?php echo $jsPatchArray ?>];

    for (i = 0; i < patches.length; i++) {

        var divIdPatch = "\"#initialData-" +patches[i]+ "\"";   

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "initial_data.php",
            data: {patch:patches[i]},
            success: function( data ) {
                $( divIdPatch ).html( data );
            }
        });


    };


    var divIdCount = "#srCount";

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "sr_count.php",
        success: function( data ) {
            $( divIdCount ).html( data ); 
        }
    });

}
</script>

<?php
$_SESSION['patchObjs'] = array();

foreach ($arrayRelQA as $patch)
{
    echo "\n";
    echo '<div id="initialData-'.$patch.'"></div>';
}
echo "\n<div id=\"srCount\"></div>";
```

From the above this part works fine:

```
var divIdCount = "#srCount";

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "sr_count.php",
    success: function( data ) {
        $( divIdCount ).html( data ); 
    }
});
```

However the loop section does not - the ajax and the underlying `initial_data.php` is being executed however the success is not finding my div (`divIdPatch`). Must be something to do with how I'm constructing the var `divIdPatch`. I've tried the following (and various other variants:

```
var divIdPatch = "\"#initialData-" +patches[i]+ "\"";   
var divIdPatch = "#initialData-" +patches[i];;
```

### Subsequent investigation / edit

It looks like the ajax is messing with the for loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < patches.length; i++) {

    var patch = patches[i];
    var divIdPatch = "#initialData-" +patches[i]; 

    alert("Outside: "+patch );
    alert( "Outside: "+divIdPatch );        

    $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        url: "initial_data.php",
        data: {patch:patch},
        success: function( data ) {

            alert( "Inside Div: "+divIdPatch);
            alert( "Inside Data: "+data);
            $( divIdPatch ).html( data );
        }
    });


};
```

The alerts fire in this order (3 pacthes in the array)
Note the patch order on the 'Inside Div' alert:

```
Outside: patch 1
Outside: #initialData-patch 1
Inside Div: #initialData-patch 2
Inside Data: Patch 1 complete.

Outside: patch 2
Outside: #initialData-patch 2
Inside Div: #initialData-patch 3
Inside Data: Patch 2 complete.

Outside: patch 3
Outside: #initialData-patch 3
Inside Div: #initialData-patch 3
Inside Data: Patch 3 complete.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the jquery ajax success function could not find the divs in the html if the id contained spaces. (after using console.log I confirmed the flow in the ajax was in fact correct - noobie to js!).

Original php code was generating divs like:

```
<div id="initialData patch 0"></div>
```

The JS divId var in the below was being formed correctly, e.g.:

```
var divId = "#initialData patch 0"
```

but the following code wasn't finding the divs:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: script,
    data: {patch:data},
    success: function( response ) {     
        $( divId ).html( response );
    }
});
```

After updating the .php & JS to construct and search for divs without the spaces the problem was solved, e.g:

```
<div id="initialData-patch-0"></div>
```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Apologies - one addition the flow was correct after I moved the ajax to a separate function and called that func from insdie the loop.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
  var divIdPatch = "\"#initialData-" +patches[i]+ "\"";
```

should be:

```
var divIdPatch = "#initialData-" +patches[i];
```

Comment: Thanks Irfan - I did try that before posting (I realise there's a typo in the code above) and just re-tested. It did not work, must be something to do with js for loop, but I can't figure out what - I'm new to js.

Comment: there must be an error in your ajax request. put an alert inside success event and see

Comment: alert($( divIdPatch )); put this alert inside as well. and see what it shows.@DaveF

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if js could run a php script. 
But You could write another service on server to provide $jsPatchArray on response then retrieve it on client via another ajax then do the loop to call "initial_data.php" on success retrieving $jsPatchArray.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "service_to_retrieve_jsPatchArray.php",

            success: function( jsPatchArray ) {
               // do your loop here. 
            }
        });
```

or another way, you can put $jsPatchArray on html then js grab it from accessing html element.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax by definition allows code to execute outside the context of the calling script. Your JavaScript is making Ajax calls and returning data before the divs are actually in the Dom. Wrap your function in a $(document).ready function and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for replying - the code snippet in the above is not the entire .php script. I have a <body onload="initialData()"> - think that ensures the initialData() is only actioned after the page has loaded.